# Having trouble writing a code that extracts words from a sentence, and prints them line by line. Algorithm below. i'm using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

ask the user for a sentence,

variable last_index will store the starting location of a given word in the input sentence – initialize it to 0,

while True

use find to find the next blank (i.e., “ “) in the sentence by asking find to start looking for the blank at index last_index AND assign the index returned by find to a variable called blank_index

if there are still blanks to be processed (i.e., find did not return -1)

- use the splice operator to extract a word from last_index up to blank_index and print the word
- update last_index to be the location directly after blank_index (i.e., assign blank_index + 1 to last_index)
  otherwise there are no more blanks to be processed (this means blank_index is equal to -1)

  use the splice operator to extract the last word from the user’s string (starting at last_index, and ending at the last character in the string, obtained by using the len function) and print that word
  break out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way: .split()

Usage:
string.split(point_to_split).

It returns an array. In your case:

```
sentence = input("Enter your sentence")
sentence_arr = sentence.split(" ")
```

Will ask for a sentence, then split it into words. eg. "split is useful" goes to ["split","is","useful"]